# Wordpress not loading images

Tags: php, wordpress

my wordress has completely stopped loading images, even the dashboard icons appear as broken, I followed a few videos about changing permissions but to no avail, currently am using `755` permissions and running wordpress `4.9.5` I am using the `Sydney theme` here are a few snippets
[Themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa3xe.png)

enter image description here

[Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PoPw.png)

[The dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jidf6.png)

[Network tab results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9EH9.png)

I have to stress out the fact that this happened overnight, I went to bed yesterday with a fully working website woke up today with the site down.

Comment: If you open up the console (Press F12 on your keyboard and click console in Chrome browser). Does it say anything about blocked cross site traffic or something? Are the pages hosted on the same site as the wordpress page?

Comment: @ThomasDarvik they are hosted on the same site but what I noticed from the console is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` and `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Comment: Can you click the network tab, and check what you get there? (That is the network tab in the dev tools , also F12)

Comment: @ThomasDarvik  I have added a snipped of the output by the network tab please check it our

Comment: I had similar issues on a wordpress site. It was due to my host's protection mechanism. Given I was hitting my own site quite a bit, I was triggering the host's self-defense mechanism.

Comment: @DavidBrossard my host is bluehost, any change you know how to deal with this?

Comment: I would reach out to them and ask. That's what I did (on a different host). For what it's worth, I had issues due to DoS protection and a switch to SSL (also check that your images are loaded over HTTPS if you access your site over HTTPS). My setup was an nginx (which I have no control or visibility over) in front of Apache Server with PHP_mod.

Comment: https://helpchat.bluehost.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your website is facing a problem cause it worked for me, maybe your internet connection may got confused to load up the images and check the problem from your devices, if you need a personal assist on fixing the problem, contact me

Comment: I get these errors from the console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) and Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`